# ui-router: Reset $state without using $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, reload

First off, I think the overall issue here is that AngularJS still doesn't have a sensible, best practice way of "restarting" the app and all its components. So far, the best practice seems to be setting the path to a "default" view, and then reloading the window. We do this in our /logout state, as seen here:

```
$stateProvider.state('logout', {
    onEnter: function($state, $window, store) {
        //Remove any session variables
        store.remove('varA');
        store.remove('varB');

        //"Logout" the user
        $state.go('login');
        $window.location.reload();
    }
})
```

However, this is a bad user experience. The user can actually see the view change and the components on the page shift before the window reloads. It just seems very buggy overall.

Originally, we did not include `$state.go('login')`, and did not get the weird experience of seeing the view change before logout. However, when we started using $state handlers like `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams)`, we noticed that `toState` was not being reset after the window reload. So `$stateChangeStart` would trigger after the reload, and `toState` would still be set to whatever view the user was on before calling `/logout`. This isn't a true app reset!

**Possible Solution:** I think all of this can be solved if there was a way to "reset $state" without using the `$state.go()` method...something that happens behind the scenes instead.

Comment: Check out `state.transitionTo()` and its various options. Also, `$state.reload()` http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Have you tried `window.history.go(-window.history.length-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code change fixed it for me

```
//"Logout" the user
$state.go('login', null, {notify: false}).then(function() {
    $window.location.reload();
});
```

Source: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2486#issuecomment-180872463